# How does apt upgrade running programs?

Tags: apt

I wonder how ***apt upgrade*** does upgrade running programs.

Does it wait until the program terminates?

Does it simply overwrite the files while the program is running? Doesn't this interfere the running program?

And what about shared libraries?

Comment: [How can Ubuntu update running applications without having to close them while Windows cannot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/150485/how-can-ubuntu-update-running-applications-without-having-to-close-them-while-wi)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does it wait until the program terminates?

Maybe, depending on the package.

> Does it simply overwrite the files while the program is running? Doesn't this interfere the running program?

It can, depending on the program and the files.

> And what about shared libraries?

It depends on whether it has been loaded into memory yet. https://stackoverflow.com/a/7767402/1212596

---

## Full answer

Apt (actually, the underlying dpkg) runs scripts when uninstalling and installing a package. If the package includes a long-running program (daemon), it is usually stopped when the old version of the package is removed, and started when the new version of the package is installed.

> *preinst*
> This script is executed before the package it belongs to is unpacked from its Debian archive (".deb") file. Many 'preinst' scripts stop services for packages which are being upgraded until their installation or upgrade is completed (following the successful execution of the 'postinst' script).
>
> *postinst*
> This script typically completes any required configuration of the package foo once foo has been unpacked from its Debian archive (".deb") file. Often, 'postinst' scripts ask users for input, and/or warn them that if they accept default values, they should remember to go back and re-configure that package as needed. Many 'postinst' scripts then **execute any commands necessary to start or restart a service** once a new package has been installed or upgraded.
>
> *prerm*
> **This script typically stops any daemons** which are associated with a package. It is executed before the removal of files associated with the package.
>
> *postrm*
> This script typically modifies links or other files associated with foo, and/or removes files created by the package. (Also see What is a Virtual Package?, Section 7.8.)
>
> https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-faq/ch-pkg_basics.en.html

It is of course up to the package maintainer to start and stop services in postinst and prerm.

Answer (score 49):

In POSIX (and Linux is a POSIX system), at least when using POSIX file systems, files are allowed to remain open after they're deleted (that is, after they're *[unlinked](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/unlink.html)*, by removing the link from a particular file name to the underlying inode object, which is what actually identifies a particular string of bytes as the contents of a file). Files in this state continue to be accessible to code that has an open handle to them (a file descriptor in the user land, other structures in the kernel land), although they no longer have a name<sup>1</sup> and anything that tries to open the old name will no longer be able to get them. This means that if you do the following:

```
$ cat /tmp/foo.txt # step 1
foo
$ rm /tmp/foo.txt # step 2
$ echo "bar" > /tmp/foo.txt # step 3
```

You're not actually changing the contents of `/tmp/foo.txt`, rather, you're creating a new, *unrelated and independent* file that is accessible under the same name whilst the old file no longer is.

Furthermore, POSIX also provides for *atomic renames*, in which a file is instantly renamed to an existing name, and replaces the original file with no intermediate states. In essence, it's a mechanism which guarantees that nothing will be able to get between step 2 and step 3 above and see the old file deleted but the new one not in place yet.

When `apt` upgrades a binary that is running, it doesn't actually change the file's contents; instead it uses atomic renames to instantly whisk the new (and completely independent, as described above) file from a temporary name into the old one's place. Anything that had the old file open (this includes processes running it as an executable) will continue to see and use the old contents as if nothing ever happened. But when the process terminates and is restarted, its code will be looked up by name, so the new contents will be used. This also means that it's possible to have processes executing the same named binary, yet running different code.

Note however that the above only applies to individual files. There's nothing to allow atomic replacement of all of an application's resources if they're spread across multiple files, so if, for example, the binary loads a shared library dynamically, or opens some data by name after it's been started, it very well might see something it wasn't expecting and malfunction and/or crash. That's why you get the popup telling you to restart Firefox after it's been upgraded "or you will experience issues".

<sup>1</sup> More properly, they no longer have *that particular name*, as files (that is, inodes) are allowed to be accessible under multiple names. The vast majority of files however only ever have one name, and when they're unliked from it, they will be deleted<sup>2</sup> as soon as nothing has them open anymore.

<sup>2</sup> This deferred deletion is also why, in some cases, you might delete files to reclaim disk space, only to discover that no space was freed. That's because something has those files open and keeps them in that zombie, nameless-yet-alive state.

Comment: _"files are allowed to be opened after they're deleted"_ - I know what you mean, but that sounds wrong. Perhaps change it to something like "files are allowed to be kept open after they're deleted"?

Comment: @marcelm or "files are allowed to *stay* opened after they're deleted".

Comment: And this is why you need to run `sudo checkrestart` after an upgrade.

Comment: I submitted an edit.  Instead of "files are allowed to be opened" I made it "files are allowed to remain open".  The "-ed" makes a huge difference.

Comment: Awesome answer. A social experiment you can do is play a song using VLC, then while it's playing, rename or delete the file. The song will continue playing till end but if you try to play it again, you will get the "file does not exist" error. Pretty cool.

Comment: @Parto: I don't get why it should be a social experiment, though.

Comment: @marcelm technically, you can open files after they're deleted (but still opened by a process), by opening the magic links under `/proc/$pid/fd/`

Comment: @rav_kr Haha, I was wondering if someone would bring that up. You're right of course, but that's very likely not what the answerer meant in this context (apt upgrading files). It's also why I used _"sounds wrong"_ instead of _"is wrong"_; because yes, _technically_ he was correct, although probably unintentionally :)

Answer (score 13):

`apt upgrade` overwirites files. It doesn't affect running programs, because they are loaded to RAM. If you restart a program, a new version will start.

When upgrading some packages, some triggers or scripts may be run to restart some services if this is needed.

Comment: What happens if files are deleted (because they are no longer in the new version) and the running program still needs them?

Comment: Package maintainers aeresponsible for all such cases. Ut is too broad to ask generally "if something happens".

Comment: @somega: already opened files - when deleted - stay on disc/in RAM until they're closed. The running outdated program can't open deleted files though.

Comment: @Nyos "stay on disc/in RAM" - on disk. This is especially visible when deleting large (log) files that remain opened, to see that `df` still displays the non-freed disk space while `ls` no longer lists the file.

Comment: @somega Program developers can write upgrades such that they never end up deleting files used by the previous version. So when you upgrade the old version can still run without issues and when you restart it is going to use the new files. This is done also for migrating DB tables. If you want to do a "live" upgrade you need to do it in multiple steps: add a new column to a table, move data from the old column to the new one (or better just copy it), finally remove the old column when it is not used anymore. Unfortuantely it's more costly then just ignoring the problem.

Comment: @Pilot6 I disagree that it's too broad to ask "if something happens". That's the point of the question which this answer doesn't actually address.

Comment: I like @Pilot6 answer. And this is what i expected before asking. I think the package maintainers know how the programs work and can thus adopt their update scripts to whatever the program's requirements are.

Comment: “running programs […] are loaded to RAM“ is a good starting point for the concept that running processes are independent of the names (i. e. file system links) of the files that were used to initialise their process images. Of course, in practice, it’s more complicated than that: running processes may be swapped out of RAM incl. their images, clean (unmodified) memory pages backed by files aren’t swapped because they already have non-volatile copies, file systems can retain files after they were unlinked as long as something still holds a reference to them (e. g. the virtual memory manager).